# first match every line regex notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have a bulk process to do this using notepad++ regex

abcd:1234:12342:13234

abcde:123431:1234123:1234

abcdqsd:1231234:1234123:1234

abcdzza:121234:1234123:1234

abcdzzs:1234231:2311234:1234

i need to remove first match separated by : delimiter every line

**list becomes**

1234:12342:13234

123431:1234123:1234

1231234:1234123:1234

121234:1234123:1234

1234231:2311234:1234

i ve tried

.*:

but it selects 2 first matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.*:` matches zero or more characters other than a newline (without DOTALL modifier) up to the *last* occurrence of `:` on a line.

You can use the following regex:

```
^[^:\n\r]*:(.*)
```

and replace with `$1`.

*Explanation:*

- `^` - start of line
- `[^:\n\r]*` - zero or more characters other than `:` and linebreaks
- `:` a literal `:`
- `(.*)` - Group 1: all the rest of the line that will backreference with `$1` in the replacement pattern (since we want to keep it).

[image]

Comment: @Zereges: No, it does not. At least in my Notepad++ v.6.8.8

Comment: @stribizhev It does in PSPad, so I thought it could also in notepad++

Comment: The problem with just `^[^:\r\n]*:` that I tried (same but more efficient than `^.*?:`) is that the replacements are done in a loop. Even when I ticked off *Wrap around* it removed more than I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

Find what: `^\w+:(.*)`
Replace with: `$1`